# ng-option within ng-repeat how do I update the model not to include a selected value from another select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

Difficult question to put into words but basically I have an ng-option select box within an ng-repeat. In my current situation this causes the select box to appear 3 times as the option can be used on 3 different things.

If I select a value from the first select box then I need that to be removed from the other 2.

Here is a JSFiddle with a primitive example of the issue

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in test" ng-model="test.name">
```

**jsFiddle:** http://plnkr.co/edit/inrM2ZUOc7hEhSHgps9P?p=preview

Thanks in advance

Comment: Version you are using is far too old. Current versions don't support using global functions for controllers. Upgrading will help for this situation to allow using features that have been enhanced

Comment: @charlietfl apologies I'm actually using a recent version. I just forked that fiddle from another plunk

Comment: If you're using 1.4 you can use the `disable when` syntax. Otherwise I think the easiest way is to use an `ng-repeat` for the options with an `ng-if` or `ng-show`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter in the ng-repeat to exclude the selected options.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bmr0OeK8pgsuZFamMqSJ?p=preview)

```
<select 
  ng-options="item as item.name for item in test | filter:'!'+selected"
  ng-model="test.name">
```